# Grunt task exit too early

Tags: node.js, gruntjs

I have this script that watches over files in a directory

```
// the_script.js

var fs = require('fs');

fs.watch('someDir', function() {
    console.log('I see you');
});
```

I run it with

```
node the_script.js
```

and it correctly keeps running forever.

Now I'd like to make it a grunt task, but if I write the task as

```
// Gruntfile.js

module.exports = function(grunt) {
    grunt.registerTask('default', function(grunt) {
        console.log('loading task');

        var fs = require('fs');

        fs.watch('someDir', function() {
            console.log('I see you');
        });
    });    
};
```

when I run

```
grunt
```

I just see "loading task" and than the process exits.

I want to know how to make the grunt task run forever and understand what's happening.

Answer (score 0):

I only have `gulp` experience and from what I recall `gulp` executes and then terminates and if grunt is similar and you need to force it to stay open then try reading from the console (example, via the `readline` npm module):

https://www.npmjs.com/package/readline